# Dynamic types from arrays for a class method

Tags: typescript

I would like to get the values from an array as types, something like this:

```
const chars = ['a','b','c'] as const

type TChars = typeof chars[number] // 'a'| 'b' | 'c'
```

I would like to do the same but for `class` methods and properties, like this:

```
class Test{
  constructor(public chars:string[]){}

  get(char:string){
    return char
  }
}

new Test(['a','b','c']).get('d') //error only allow a,b or c
```

So the `get()` method should only allow the initial characters passed to the `constructor`.

I am open to refactoring the class signature.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEAVApjALgb1PeYD2AdugE4CuYaexAFAA6kBGEAlmLgBZTEwBcJzBAOYBtALoBKDAF9Q2eIORpqYTsT5piAwZLk5ii0sQIcucmSHOgCyAO5JUS4QHIoTgDROG7p2CcSAdApKTgAmTuLwAPSRyMTEVPCEEACe8FAQEHh2UG4MicS4siCg+ERoJtzwALzwzq4eXh6+omkIpehFaMm0yEgAwqoINV09eABmFTDCBKQAtgyxLdHwLk4APite8Bs+TqBAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost exactly the same way, except you need to make the class the generic and then use that generic to tell `get` to only accept the values in the array.

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/4w1JON)

```ts
class Test<T extends readonly string[]> {
  constructor(public chars: T) {}

  get(char: T[number]) {
    return char;
  }
}

//error only allow a,b or c
new Test(["a", "b", "c"] as const).get("d");
```

Comment: Thank you. For discussion purposes, is there a way to reference the `chars` property of the `class`  in the signature of the `get()` method?

Comment: Not sure if I get it right. Why does signature need to reference `chars` when it is available in the method using `this.chars`? https://tsplay.dev/jwgE0m

Comment: It has nothing to do with the current question, I was curious for future reference.
something like this: `get(char: get_access_to_class_chars_prop )`

Comment: I think that worth a new question. However, I am thinking about the motivation about it. `get` is an instance method, that means whenever `get` is called, the class must have been instanciated using the constructor, setting proper `this.chars`. In that context, whatever logic is within `get` has access to the variable and does not require injecting via method parameters. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Coming from `typeof chars[number]`  My first idea for the `oop` variant of the problem  was  `get(char: get_access_to_class_chars_prop )`. So I wanna know if that's even possible.